# How can i render a list with different types of objects in Angular?

Tags: angular, list

I Have to render a list which contains different object types. For every object according to his type i have to render different angular components. How can i do this? I have 2 ideas, one with ngSwitch and the other one to generate dynamic the components with `ComponentFactoryResolver`. My list is coming from database. what should i choose? Is there a different approach to this problem? I would appreciate it if you can tell me some pros and cons.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.